# How to change title of button A when button B is pressed?

Tags: swift, button, title

In Swift, I want to change the title of Button A when Button B is pressed.

I tried `sender.ButtonA.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)` under IBAction Button B but it couldn't work.. it was just a guess anyway..

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say "didn't work".  Did you have compiler errors?  Or did it run and just not do what you wanted?  Or did it launch missiles?

Comment: The `sender` parameter is the button that was clicked. In this case, that would be ButtonB. Check Christian's answer for how to proceed. You almost had it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the `sender` for your needs. Because `sender` is the button you've clicked on and not the one you want to change the title of.

So, you need to make an `IBOutlet` of your button like you did by creating your IBAction. Then you can call it like that:

```
yourButton.setTitle("Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```